# Dice Poker Solver

Tags: dice, poker, python, programming

Hi everyone I'm trying to program a solver for a game similar to [poker dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_dice) in Python.   The only difference lays in the fact that you are given 5 numbers at the start and choose to change two, the scores are identical, but it is a one versus one game.

The solver should take your current hand and first calculate the loose/win percentage that you have, then suggest the better alternative to take (either change one, two number or draw). Since this must be implemented I really need a function oriented answer.

I suck at probability related problems, so i have no idea on how to implement this, can anyone help?

Comment: I think that you may need to explain your variant a bit more fully.  Long ago, I did some analysis and the results were a little surprising.  I analysed two variants: the second player may roll 3 times regardless of what the first player did; the second player may only roll as many times as the first.  In the first variant, the obvious rethrow was best except in very few cases e.g. AAAAK, it was better to stick with that than hope to improve it to AAAAA.  In the second variant, it was best to stick on surprisingly low hands e.g. a pair of jacks.

Comment: My variant is the following:
The opponent player rolls once all five dices. 
You are given 5 dices already rollen and must decide if you want to change two of them (or one or neither).

Comment: So, you need to decide whether you have an expectation of bettering your hand by throwing 1 or 2 dice?  What happens if you decide not and opt to throw none - is it a draw?  Since you are a programmer, you could attack this by brute force and ignorance.  Even without bothering to eliminate unimportant differences (e.g. the order of the dice), there are only $6^5$ hands that your opponent might throw.  A program could analyse all of these in little time.  I did that decades ago (no exaggeration) on much slower machines than are available today.